# Composer Repository not Pushed

Tags: php, git, codeigniter, github

composer.json:

```
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "codeigniter/translation",
        "version": "3.1.4",
        "source": {
          "url": "https://github.com/bcit-ci/codeigniter3-translations.git",
          "type": "git",
          "reference": "master"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
 "require": {
    "codeigniter/translation": "3.1.*",
  },
```

There is no problem in using composer.
Github Commit-Push:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "test"
git push origin master
```

[image: codeigniter/translation is empty]

codeigniter/translation directory is empty. The files have not been uploaded. It has to be this way:

[image]